# GeoTools getCapabilities with no CRS in boundingbox

Tags: geotools, mapserver

I'm tring to retrieve a cababilities from a MapServer:

```
    URL url = null;
    try {
      url = new URL( sourceUrl );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      //will not happen
    }

    WebMapServer wms = null;
    try {
      wms = new WebMapServer(url);

      WMSCapabilities capabilities = wms.getCapabilities();

      String serverName = capabilities.getService().getName();
      String serverTitle = capabilities.getService().getTitle();
      System.out.println("Capabilities retrieved from server: " + serverName + " (" + serverTitle + ")");         


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bounding Box element contains no CRS/SRS attribute
    at org.geotools.ows.wms.xml.WMSComplexTypes$_BoundingBoxType.getValue(WMSComplexTypes.java:3241)
    at org.geotools.xml.handlers.ComplexElementHandler.endElement(ComplexElementHandler.java:140)
    at org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler.endElement(XMLSAXHandler.java:252)
    ... 87 more
```

The capabilities XML is like this ( the important part ):

[image]

As I can see, the boundingbox is really without a CRS but I can do nothing about this since it is not my server.

How can I proceed?

Comment: What version of mapserver is this? it will say in the top of the GetCapabilities response

Comment: @user27874 thanks but it is not relevant anymore. Already get a workaround.

Comment: Good that you have a workaround, but would still be nice to know which version of MapServer that has/had the problem so that can see if there's a need to file a bug, or upgrade etc.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find this. Not working on this anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to file a [bug report with the MapServer team](https://mapserver.org/development/bugs.html). `CRS` is a mandatory element and you can't leave it blank and expect to make the bounding box make sense. In an ideal world GeoTools could fall back on the `Ex_GeographicBoundingBox` but that would be no help here either.

It is also worth contacting the owner of the server and asking them to fix the configuration of that layer.